# Python get start and end date of the week

Tags: python, python-2.4

How to get the start date and end date of a week, and also if the following dates below comes under a particular range of start and end dates of the week how to show only those weeks start and end date.I am using python 2.4

```
2011-03-07  0:27:41
2011-03-06  0:13:41
2011-03-05  0:17:40
2011-03-04  0:55:40
2011-05-16  0:55:40
2011-07-16  0:55:40
```

Comment: Have you tried datetime module?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused reading your question. Could you use some more punctuation and explain a bit more precisely?

Comment: First and last day of the week depends on locale. Eg first day can be Sunday or Monday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import strptime
```

Now

```
datetime(*strptime('2011-03-08  0:27:41', '%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S')[0:6]).weekday()
```

returns the [day of the week](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.date.weekday) for the first date "as an integer, where Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6", so selecting those dates for which `weekday() in [0, 6]` will give you the start and end dates of weeks (or use 4 instead of 6 for work weeks).

Answer (score 0):

From python2.5 onwards datetime module has `datetime.strptime(date_string, format)` which you can pass the date_string and format to get a datetime object for doing comparisions. In python2.4, you could use the time module's support of strptime. From the documentation, you should be able to find the week part of your question.